# How to get multiline tooltip for a list control on a dialog box?

Tags: c++, mfc, tooltip, listcontrol

As text on my list box is very huge I am trying to get multiline a tooltip on the list control.

```
BOOL CTestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    mylist.EnableToolTips(TRUE);
    mylist.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_INFOTIP | mylist.GetExtendedStyle());

    mylist.InsertColumn(0, L"suri", LVCFMT_LEFT, 10000);
    CString str1 = L"nonNegativeInteger GetVehicleOwnerHolderByRegNumAndDateResponse.GetVehicleOwnerHolderByRegNumAndDateResult[optional].GetVehicleOwnerHolderByRegNumAndDateResultType.VHOwnerHolderResponse.VHOwnerHolderResponseType.Body.VehicleCountries.VehicleCountriesType.VehicleCountry[1, unbound].VehicleCountryType.VehCountryReplies.VehCountryRepliesType.VehCountryReply[1, unbound].Messages[optional].Message[1, unbound].MessageType.MessageCode"; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++) {
        CString str2;
        str2.Format(L"%d",i);
        str2 = str2 + str1;
        mylist.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM, i, str2, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
    }

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

I am getting following output which is truncated text i.e complete text is missing.
  [image]

How to get text on tooltip multiline?

EDIT: I used following also.
still same result.

```
CToolTipCtrl* pToolTip = AfxGetModuleThreadState()->m_pToolTip;
   if (pToolTip)
      pToolTip->SetMaxTipWidth(SHRT_MAX);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get multi-line tooltips using newlines-charecters with `SetMaxTipWidth()` set to a large value. And if calling `SetMaxTipWidth()` with a small value, then it will automatically break into multiple lines when meeting a space-character.

You need to subclass your tooltip/infotip in order to use it:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CListCtrl_InfoTip, CListCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX(LVN_GETINFOTIP, OnGetInfoTip)
    ON_NOTIFY_EX(TTN_NEEDTEXTA, 0, OnToolNeedText)
    ON_NOTIFY_EX(TTN_NEEDTEXTW, 0, OnToolNeedText)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CListCtrl_InfoTip::PreSubclassWindow()
{
    CListCtrl::PreSubclassWindow();
    SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_INFOTIP | GetExtendedStyle());
}

BOOL CListCtrl_InfoTip::OnGetInfoTip(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    // Will only request tooltip for the label-column
    NMLVGETINFOTIP* pInfoTip = (NMLVGETINFOTIP*)pNMHDR;
    CString tooltip = GetToolTipText(pInfoTip->iItem, pInfoTip->iSubItem);
    if (!tooltip.IsEmpty())
    {
        _tcsncpy(pInfoTip->pszText, static_cast<LPCTSTR>(tooltip), pInfoTip->cchTextMax);
    }
    return FALSE;    // Let parent-dialog get chance
}

BOOL CListCtrl_InfoTip::OnToolNeedText(UINT id, NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
...
   // Break tooltip into multiple lines if it contains newlines (\r\n)
   CToolTipCtrl* pToolTip = AfxGetModuleThreadState()->m_pToolTip;
   if (pToolTip)
      pToolTip->SetMaxTipWidth(SHRT_MAX);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to consider:

**1. The size of the window**

To activate multilines mode. This instruction is sufficient :

```
 pToolTip->SetMaxTipWidth(SHRT_MAX);
```

**2. Number of characters to display**

For this second point it is necessary to be wary because the size of the field **pszText** is limited to **80 characters**:

```
typedef struct tagNMTTDISPINFOA {
NMHDR hdr;
LPSTR lpszText;
char szText[80];
...
}
```

Therefore, even if you change **SetMaxTipWidth** you will not see any difference.
I suggest you to use the **lpszText** field which has no limit. Below is the code fragment that interests you:

```
pTTTW->lpszText = T2W (strTipText.GetBuffer (strTipText.GetLength ()));
```

Where **strTipText** is the CString that contains the message to show in the pop-up